# System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache in MonoTouch

Tags: .net, xamarin.ios, memorycache

Is the [System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) accessible in MonoTouch? If not, does anyone know of an equivalent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.Runtime.Caching.dll` does not exists in the mobile (SilverLight superset) profile used in MonoTouch (and Mono for Android).

It is [supported](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Caching/System.Runtime.Caching/MemoryCache.cs) by Mono 2.11 (*unstable*) so it may become available in the future. IOW MonoTouch will rebased on Mono 2.12 (i.e. 2.11 promoted to stable). Right now MonoTouch is following the *stable* Mono 2.10 branch.

Of course since Mono is open source you can compile/try it inside your own application.